# What is wrong with the recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

I tried to search a tree node with a specific value in a binary search tree.
So I used recursion, but it didn't worked well. 
I want to know what is wrong with the function.

Someone said I should return the function when I call it in itself.
It actually worked, but I don't understand why. Can someone explain to me how 
 recursion really works and what if the return type is void?
Thank you!

```
typedef struct node
{
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    int val;
}treeNode;
int searchTree(treeNode *T, int key, treeNode *T1, treeNode** p)
{
    if(!T)
    {
        *p=T1;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(T->val==key)
    {
        *p=T;
        return 1;
    }
    else if(T->val<key)
    {
        searchTree(T->right,key,T,p);
    }
    else
    {
        searchTree(T->left,key,T,p);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "it didn't worked well" meaning what, exactly?

Comment: You should not `return 1` for the child searches but rather what the inner calls to `searchTree` return.

Comment: "It didn't work well" means when I use searchTree to insert an array with a for loop, only the first element  of the array is inserted.

Comment: You aren't using the return value from searchTree

Comment: Could you explain why should I use return value from search Tree?

Comment: Im confused about what the purpose of p and T1 are

Comment: If you don't use the return value your function will only ever return 1 or 0...

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed to return the value of the recursive call

if you need to do a recursive call this is not for nothing ;-)

```
int searchTree(treeNode *T, int key, treeNode *T1, treeNode** p)
{
    if(!T)
    {
        *p=T1;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(T->val==key)
    {
        *p=T;
        return 1;
    }
    else if(T->val<key)
    {
        return searchTree(T->right,key,T,p);
    }
    else
    {
        return searchTree(T->left,key,T,p);
    }
}
```

Note that because the recursion is *terminal* the compiler can remove it and produce a loop ...and you can do that by yourself too ;-)

Comment: Hello  Liu, again  ;-)

Comment: that depends on the case, here it is just an _int_ so the value can be returned in a register, else it is in the stack

Comment: there you go we have a chat link